# Android Google Maps animating every location

Tags: java, android, animation

I have an ArrayList of LatLng, and in a forloop of onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) I would like to animate moving from location to another in order.

I tried doing this in a for loop:

```
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(currLatLng,10), 1000, null);
```

and the animation happens only at the last location.

How would I go about doing so? Should I use the last parameter of animateCamera() method? (Cancellable Callback)

Comment: Just check if addling a delay between for loops work to the set time 1s

Comment: @Nobody simple addition of Thread.sleep() and Handler.postDelayed() does not work. Also I am not a fan of adding Thread.sleep in Android activities (as it is illegal to do so in UI threads).

Answer (score 0):

My instinct was correct.
The last parameter in `animateCamera` is a `CancellableCallback()` interface.
What I did is made a method called a`nimateToLocationAtIndex(int index)`

And then called:

```
mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 10), 2000, new GoogleMap.CancelableCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            // Placing a marker on the position after animated
            Marker marker = mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
            animateLocationMovement(i+1);
        }
```

This animates the locations as I wanted, although I ran into another issue where the map at the next location isn't loaded so it may seem like the animation is laggy.